# FTP server crashes

Tags: java, ftp

I try to create an FTP server with java to test an other aplication, but when i try to start the server, it's crashes. It's the code:

Imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServer;
import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Authority;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpReply;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpRequest;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpSession;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Ftplet;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpletContext;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpletResult;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PasswordEncryptor;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PropertiesUserManagerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.WritePermission;
```

Code:

```
public class FTPServerTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
    factory.setPort(36000);
    serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("Z:\\Winteco98\\FTPUssers\\myusers.properties"));
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new PasswordEncryptor()
    {//We store clear-text passwords in this example

            @Override
            public String encrypt(String password) {
                return password;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(String passwordToCheck, String storedPassword) {
                return passwordToCheck.equals(storedPassword);
            }
        });
        //Let's add a user, since our myusers.properties files is empty on our first test run
        BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
        user.setName("ProdeWin");
        user.setPassword("ProdeWinW98");
        user.setHomeDirectory("Z:\\Winteco98\\FTPUssers");
        List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<Authority>();
        authorities.add(new WritePermission());
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
        try
        {
            um.save(user);//Save the user to the user list on the filesystem
        }
        catch (FtpException e1)
        {
            //Deal with exception as you need
        }
        serverFactory.setUserManager(um);
        Map<String, Ftplet> m = new HashMap<String, Ftplet>();
        m.put("miaFtplet", new Ftplet()
        {

            @Override
            public void init(FtpletContext ftpletContext) throws FtpException {
                //System.out.println("init");
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy() {
                //System.out.println("destroy");
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }

            @Override
            public FtpletResult beforeCommand(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request) throws FtpException, IOException
            {

                //System.out.println("beforeCommand " + session.getUserArgument() + " : " + session.toString() + " | " + request.getArgument() + " : " + request.getCommand() + " : " + request.getRequestLine());
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                //do something
                return FtpletResult.DEFAULT;//...or return accordingly
            }

            @Override
            public FtpletResult afterCommand(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request, FtpReply reply) throws FtpException, IOException
            {
                //System.out.println("afterCommand " + session.getUserArgument() + " : " + session.toString() + " | " + request.getArgument() + " : " + request.getCommand() + " : " + request.getRequestLine() + " | " + reply.getMessage() + " : " + reply.toString());
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                //do something
                return FtpletResult.DEFAULT;//...or return accordingly
            }

            @Override
            public FtpletResult onConnect(FtpSession session) throws FtpException, IOException
            {
                //System.out.println("onConnect " + session.getUserArgument() + " : " + session.toString());
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                //do something
                return FtpletResult.DEFAULT;//...or return accordingly
            }

            @Override
            public FtpletResult onDisconnect(FtpSession session) throws FtpException, IOException
            {
                //System.out.println("onDisconnect " + session.getUserArgument() + " : " + session.toString());
                //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                //do something
                return FtpletResult.DEFAULT;//...or return accordingly
            }
        });
        serverFactory.setFtplets(m);
        //Map<String, Ftplet> mappa = serverFactory.getFtplets();
        //System.out.println(mappa.size());
        //System.out.println("Thread #" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        //System.out.println(mappa.toString());
        FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer();
        try
        {
            server.start();//Your FTP server starts listening for incoming FTP-connections, using the configuration options previously set
        }
        catch (FtpException ex)
        {
            //Deal with exception as you need
        }

}
```

And, finaly, the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/filter/executor/OrderedThreadPoolExecutor
    at org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory.<init>(FtpServerFactory.java:51)
    at mainPackage.FTPServerTest.main(FTPServerTest.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I haven't idea where does the error, please, help me.

Comment: You are missing the jar file for org.apache.mina in your classpath Sherlock!!! Google how to solve jar file in classpath issue... Good luck. Also, creating a FTP server from scratch aint a good idea.

Comment: I need test a ftp client, how i do if not have an ftp server??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mina jar file in your project library path. Find below download link for jar file.

[Mina Jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/apache-mina/apache-mina.jar.zip)

Comment: I add mina jar and when i execute the program, it is the result: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServerContext.<init>'

Comment: (DefaultFtpServerContext.java:63)
 at org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory.<init>(FtpServerFactory.java:51)
 at mainPackage.FTPServerTest.main(FTPServerTest.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 3 more

Comment: when you get such type of exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory` so need to add required library in your project lib path here you need to add loggerFactory jar file find here. [www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/slf4j/slf4j.jar.zip]